# Cannot read property '_id' of undefined express mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

```
router.get('/profile',function(req,res,next){

  User.findOne({_id : req.user._id },function(err,user){

    if(err) next(err);

    res.render('/accoutns/profile',{user:user});
  });

  });
```

Comment: above code is working ,there was spelling mistake.

Comment: what was the spelling mistake. I hope you didn't edited the question to correct your spelling mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You should use  User.findById instead of User.findOne.

```
User.findById(req.user._id, function (err, user) { 
    if(err) next(err);
    res.render('/accoutns/profile',{user:user});
    });
});
```

Comment: ReferenceError: id is not defined
   at E:\ecommerce\routes\user.js:25:17

Comment: use req.user._id or req.user.id, I though you would understand that.